# Python 3 Tkinter: error when adding image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to import an image and set it as a label but when i do, i get a error. Anyone know how to fix this? (I have tried many different file formats for the picture but it dint work)

error - _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "pic.png"

thanks

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500, highlightthickness = 0)
c.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, 1, 1)
r = 2

def update():
    global r, oval
    if r < 500:
        r += 5
    else:
        b.destroy()

    c.delete(oval)
    oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, r, r)
    root.after(50, update)

b = Button(text = "123", command = update, cursor = "iron_cross")
b.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

z = PhotoImage(file='pic.png')
label = Label(image = z)
label.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: png is not support by tkinter. You might need to install PIL. [Photoimage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: There are more than a dozen questions on this site with that exact error message (not counting the filename). Have you researched them to see if they solve your problem?

Comment: what file types are supported?

Comment: Tkinter by default supports  GIF / PGM / PPM. For anything else you will need to import PIL ([Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)) Bryan is right though. You could have got your answer by a simple google search with that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PhotoImage Tkinter module doesn't support PNG images, you need to convert the image to a GIF image and then it will work. You can also install the PIL module.

[Convert a PNG to GIF](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/png-to-gif)

[Install PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)